# Anagrams function doesn't work when copying array to lower

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

So I have an anagram function that accepts two string values. **Both strings are initialized with char[100] and the input is user input through the keyboard.**

```
bool isAnagram(char* pattern, char* string) {
    
    int count[256] = {0};
    int count2[256] = {0};
    int i;
    
    for (i = 0; pattern[i] && string[i]; i++) {
        count[pattern[i]]++;
        count2[string[i]]++;
        
    }
    if (pattern[i] || string[i]) {
        return false;
        
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        if (count[i] != count2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
    
}
```

However there's one big problem with this function: it's case sensitive. I want all anagrams including case insensitive.

I tried many different ways of copying the strings to a new temporary lowercase array.

```
bool isAnagram(char* pattern, char* string) {
    char tempstr[100];
    char tempstr2[100]; 
    int count[256] = {0};
    int count2[256] = {0};
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(pattern); i++) {
        tempstr[i] = tolower(pattern[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        tempstr2[i] = tolower(string[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; tempstr[i] && tempstr2[i]; i++) {
        count[tempstr[i]]++;
        count2[tempstr2[i]]++;
        
    }
    if (tempstr[i] || tempstr2[i]) {
        return false;
        
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        if (count[i] != count2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
    
    
}
```

That is just one way I tried. I even tried completely different methods of making anagrams. No matter what I did I could not copy the array while also checking for the anagrams with lowercase correctly.

Honestly I feel miffed. I've been very stressed lately and I don't know what i'm even doing wrong anymore. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the condition for being an anagram? Just being a permutation? Because usually anagrams are meaningful words... In any case: don't mess around with copying strings, just read each string character by character and apply `toupper((unsigned char)c)` before counting. Note the cast to unsigned, this is necessary as `toupper` (or `tolower`) accept an `int` and in case of char being signed and containing a character from extended ASCII range ([128;255]) you'd get invalid results.

Comment: Once converted to the same case, I might use `qsort` to sort the char arrays, then simply `strcmp` them to check for equality.

Comment: How would you want to handle digits, whitespace or punctuation marks, by the way? You might entirely ignore any of these (use `isalpha` – again with the cast – to check for) or all but digits (`isalnum`).

Comment: @Chris Valid approach – just that in C `qsort` is not the most convenient to apply… Apart from you convert a linear algorithm into an `O(n*log(n))` one, not sure if that's desirable.

Comment: You don't null-terminate the temporary strings.

Comment: Don't call `strlen` in the condition of a for loop! You calculate the length again and again with every iteration. Additionally keep the scope of variables as local as possible. You don't need the value of `i` after the loop, so keep it local to the loop; together with my previous comment: `for(size_t i = 0, len = strlen(pattern); i < len; ++i) { ++counts[tolower((unsigned char)pattern[i])]; }`.

Comment: Actually you still need to iterate twice, you can do all in one single iteration profiting from the fact that C-strings are null-terminated: `for(; *pattern; ++pattern) { ++counts[tolower((unsigned char)*pattern)]; }`. You can even combine iterating over both: `for(; *pattern && *string; ++pattern, ++string) { /* count both as before */ }; if(*pattern || *string) { /* lengths differ, you can short-cut: */ return false; } /* iterate over the counts as before*/` – this latter variant is probably the most efficient you can get out...

Comment: Avoid magic numbers in code! Prefer constants instead (e.g. `#define NUM_CHARS 256`) – for array sizes you might use *once* on defining the array, that's in many cases acceptable, but from there on deduce sizes from the array as in `for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(counts)/sizeof(*counts); ++i)`. You might define a macro for to avoid having to type all this again and again, such as `#define ARRAY_LENGTH(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof(*(array)))`

Answer (score 2):

Don't be miffed. Learning to plan out the operations is what learning is all about.

Slightly modifying your (simpler) first version should provide the solution.

```
bool isAnagram( char *str1, char *str2 ) {
    unsigned char cnt1[256] = { 0 }; // 0-255 is sufficient range for tallying
    unsigned char cnt2[256] = { 0 };

    while( *str1 && *str2 ) {
        cnt1[ tolower( (unsigned char)*str1++ ) ]++;
        cnt2[ tolower( (unsigned char)*str2++ ) ]++;
    }

    if( *str1 || *str2 )
        return false;

    for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof cnt1; i++ )
        if( cnt1[i] != cnt2[i] )
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Points to note:

1. In a function like this, shorter variable names are easier to read/scan.
2. `str1` and `str2` are local and expendable; used as pointers simplifies the code.
3. Uppercase alphabetic characters will be tallied as their lowercase counterpart.
4. Casting to `unsigned char` prevents nasty *sign extension* if b7 happens to be set.
5. Your 'histogram' tallying was well conceived! Well done!
6. The array element index should be `size_t i` (never negative).

**EDIT**
If you really want to impress people, replace the `for()` loop and `return true;` with:

```
    return memcmp( cnt1, cnt2, sizeof cnt1 ) == 0;
```

Or, go even further with:

```
    return !*str1 && !*str2 && !memcmp( cnt1, cnt2, sizeof cnt1 );
```

Five lines of code expressed in one line...

Anagrams: "live", "evil", "vile", "veil"... :-)

Comment: In this specific case I'd consider pre-incrementing the counts better readable mainly due to the greater distance to the strings' post-increments.

Comment: Hopefully there are no very long strings containing containing the same character more than 255 times...

Comment: @Aconcagua A valid alternative, should the OP stick around to read the answers offered...

Comment: Parameters actually should be `char const*` – then we can 'legally' pass string literals as well (yes, they *are* `char*` in C, but I'd consider assigning them to pointer to non-const still illegal – prevents potential UB if applied consistently…).

Comment: @Aconcagua OP: "_Both strings are initialized with char[100]_"... I didn't want to clutter the condition in the `for()` loop version... With `memcmp()`, the accumulators could be `long long` if needed... :-)

Comment: @Aconcagua Sufficient unto the day...

Comment: `size_t` requires `stddef.h` being included.

Comment: @Aconcagua OP doesn't show #include's so it may be a safe presumption that the OP will figure out what is needed... Anything else?

Comment: Well, the most important things have been included anyway already before (especially the cast...), rest is more or less cosmetics ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution for you.  You were very close -- I modified your code only slightly.  Note the usage of tolower() and its placement in the code.  This will cause the count arrays to be incremented as you planned.  This results in a solution that is not case-sensitive as the output reveals.
EDIT: also note addition of cast to 'unsigned char' per comment by @Aconcagua.  Runnable code is available [here](https://godbolt.org/z/o9bvn7YP1).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> /* tolower() */
#include <stdbool.h> /* bool, true, false */
    
bool isAnagram(char* pattern, char* string) 
{
    int count[256] = {0};
    int count2[256] = {0};
    int i;
    
    for (i = 0; pattern[i] && string[i]; i++) {
        count[tolower((unsigned char)pattern[i])]++;   /* added tolower() + cast */
        count2[tolower((unsigned char)string[i])]++;   /* added tolower() + cast */
    }
    if (pattern[i] || string[i]) {
        return false;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        if (count[i] != count2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
    
}


int main () 
{
    printf("%s\n", isAnagram("Batman", "Manbat")?"TRUE":"FALSE");
    printf("%s\n", isAnagram("Batman", "Cat")?"TRUE":"FALSE");
    printf("%s\n", isAnagram("Strut", "Trust")?"TRUE":"FALSE");
  
    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE
```

Comment: If using `bool` you should probably show the include for `<stdbool.h>`

Comment: @Chris - thank you , done!   Also, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/3GK84MKaM) is runnable code if anyone wants.

Comment: You need to cast to `unsigned char` before calling any of `tolower`, `toupper`, `isalpha`, `isspace`, … – all of these accept `int`, and in case of `char` being signed and an extended ASCII character contained (range [128; 255] – or UTF-8 multibyte character – but then you have quite some other issues...) you get sign extension, a negative value and undesired/bad results.

Comment: @Aconcagua  -- thank you, agreed.  Updated!